# Rails way to put specific item at the beginning of object order in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I want to take the current Profile that's set under User and move it to the front of the ordered list.  Is there a way to do this in a model scope, or even a specific query?

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
end

class User
  has_many :profiles, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy

  # current_profile :integer
end

# This is the desired effect
profiles = current_user.profiles.to_a.delete_if {|i| i.id == current_user.current_profile}.unshift Profile.find(current_user.current_profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
current_user.profiles.order("id != #{ current_user.current_profile.id }")
```